# javascript input field or array are behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, html

i'm creating input fields from drop-down menu and values are stored in array,but the third input field is storing the value of the upper drop-down menu.Just the third input field?!?
i can find the reason why is this happening?!?
the code html:

```
    <form name="myform1">
     <select id="polja2"  onchange="Gen()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
    </form>

 <form name="myform">
 <select id="polja"  onchange="Gen()">
 <option ></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>    
</select> 
</form>

<table id="t">      
    </table>
```

javascript function Gen ()=

```
function Gen()
   {      

var val = document.getElementById("polja");
val=(val.options[val.selectedIndex].value);    

var valGrup = document.getElementById("polja2");
valGrup=(valGrup.options[valGrup.selectedIndex].value);


       var e = document.getElementById("t");

            e.innerHTML = "Vrijednosti: <br>";
            var i;
            var j;

            for(i=0;i<valGrup;i++)
            {  e.innerHTML += "Grupa: "+i+"<br>";
               e.innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='naziv" + i +"'/>"+"<br>";

              for(j=0;j<val;j++)
              {
              e.innerHTML += "<input type='number' id='polja"+j+"'/>"+"<br>";
              }
            }
      }
```

second javascript function where are values are taken and put into array

```
 function korekcija(a){

      var scores=new Array();
      var scorispis=new Array();
      var val = document.getElementById("polja");      
      val=(val.options[val.selectedIndex].value);  


     for(var i=0;i<val;i++){
     alert(scores[i]);--->**it shows that the third value is the value of the upper dropdown menu number??(the "polja2")**
    scores[i]= document.getElementById("polja"+ i).value ;
    scorispis[i]= document.getElementById("polja"+ i).value ;   
     }

       VrZaRad(scores, scorispis);   
    }
```

Comment: `val=(val.options[val.selectedIndex].value);` The `(` and `)` are pointless.

Comment: I do not understand what your problem is. Could you rephrase your question please (referring to the first paragraph)?

Comment: @newBee well,i write the values in input fields that I create from second drop down menu. like 2,2,2,2 and when i'm putting them into the array the value goes like 2,2,1,2
this "1" is the number that is in chosen in first dropdown menu (in my code i have more option value like <option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option> and the third value that goes into the array is allways one of "<option value=" "> </option>" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `"polja"+j` for the third item produces `"polja2"`, which is already used as `id` of the first dropdown.

Either change the `id` of the first `select` element, or use a different prefix when constructing dynamic DOM elements.